# Ruby - Find the ending of a filename within certain parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm needing to get secondary images for a product (which could have up to 10 images), but having a bit of an issue.  Where the issue lies is `secondary_images/#{id}_20.jpg`.  The `_20` could be anything from `_1` to `_11` and `_01` to `_30`.  Unfortunately when the images were put into the system, they weren't 100% cohesive with the naming convention.  I'd change the names, but there are over 50,000 images.  What would be the proper way accomplish this?

*This code does work if the `secondary_images/#{id}` does end in `_20`.

```
def image_url(type = nil)
    no_image = type.nil? ? 'no-image-lg.png' : 'no-image.png'
    return "//img#{rand(0..9)}.foo.com/#{no_image}" unless has_image?

    require 'net/http'
    id = sprintf('%07d', master_product_id)
    url = if type == 'secondaries'
        "//img#{rand(0..9)}.foo.com/product_images/secondary_images/#{id}_20.jpg"
      elsif type == 'thumbnail'
        "//img#{rand(0..9)}.foo.com/product_images/thumbnails/#{id}.jpg"
      else
        "//img#{rand(0..9)}.foo.com/product_images/#{id}.jpg"
      end
    url = URI.parse(URI.encode(url.to_s))
    req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    res = req.request_head(url.path)

    res.code == '200' ? url.to_s : "//img#{rand(0..9)}.foo.com/#{no_image}"
  end

  def images
    images = {}

    images['main'] = image_url
    images['thumbnail'] = image_url 'thumbnail'
    images['secondaries'] = image_url 'secondaries'
    images.to_dot
  end
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Provide some samples, not just an explanation of the file naming scheme. Also, what do you expect to get as output? I'd recommend reading "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your code needs to be runnable and demonstrate the problem. I'd recommend reducing it to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate _only_ what you're asking about. Showing the HTTP processing isn't helpful.

Comment: What sample are you looking for?  What the `#{id}` could be?  It's arbitrary really, it could be anything.  What I'm concerned with is how to search through the folder within the parameters of `_1` to `_11` or `_01` to `_30`.  I could take out all the other code, and just include the line in question, but others might find some of it useful.

Comment: Perhaps some sort of regex might do the trick?

Comment: Some sort might do the trick, but you need to provide concrete examples of your filenames. Stack Overflow isn't here just to answer your question, it's to provide a lasting answer to others who are searching for a solution to the same question in the future. We need and expect certain things in the question to help them.

Comment: Are the images stored on the same server your app is running on?

Comment: Tin Man - Wow, yes, apparently I goofed and left that part out of the original question.  The filenames are the master SKU number.  That's what I meant by it's really arbitrary what the `#{id}` in front of the `_20` is.  It would be something like this: `secondary_images/5672432_01.jpg`.

Jordan - No, they are stored on a different server.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you can use the following regex to match the corresponding digits.

```
/.*(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([1-3]\d))\.jpg\b/
```

Here's an example:

https://regex101.com/r/gJ2jU7/1

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try it out!

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to tell what you want, but perhaps it'll help to know that Ruby includes routines that make it easy to get at the filename in a path. Once you have that it's easy to extract parts of the name since it's string manipulation.

```
def get_image_num(fname)
  File.basename(fname, File.extname(fname)).split('_').last
end

[
  'secondary_images/foo_1.jpg',
  'secondary_images/foo_11.jpg',
  'secondary_images/foo_01.jpg',
  'secondary_images/foo_30.jpg',
  'secondary_images/foo_20.jpg'
].map{ |s|
  get_image_num(s)
}
# => ["1", "11", "01", "30", "20"]
```

If you need to get both the `id` value, and the file number, I'd do something like:

```
def get_image_num(fname)
  File.basename(fname, File.extname(fname)).split('_')
end

[
  'secondary_images/123_1.jpg',
  'secondary_images/123_11.jpg',
  'secondary_images/123_01.jpg',
  'secondary_images/123_30.jpg',
  'secondary_images/123_20.jpg'
].map{ |s|
  get_image_num(s)
}
# => [["123", "1"], ["123", "11"], ["123", "01"], ["123", "30"], ["123", "20"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the `.basename` at work earlier, and thought it might be useful for what I was attempting.  I will definitely try this out tomorrow at work.